# Does upgrading to w10 remove appdata in windows.old?

Tags: windows

There's only one folder in the windows.old\users\user\appdata folder, and that's Microsoft.

Is that the way it's supposed to be? I need to access some files that don't seem to have been migrated.

I have show hidden files ticked.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `AppData` folder is preserved if you chose "Keep files and settings" during the Windows upgrade.

However this folder is migrated to the new Windows version i.e `C:\Users\Username\AppData`, so if you're looking for a certain file that was in AppData of previous version, just look in the AppData of the newer version.

Please note: As much as Windows tries to preserve these files during the upgrade, not all files are saved e.g some games data (previously in this folder) consequently those not preserved I suspect they are deleted. hence only the Microsoft folder remaining.